# Сортировать массив значений

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Имеется массив

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [nameUser] => Я
    ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [nameUser] => К
    ) 
)
```

Требуется его отсортировать по полю nameUser, чтобы в итоге вышло

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [nameUser] => Я
    ) 

    [0] => Array ( 
        [nameUser] => К
    ) 
)
```

Comment: array_multisort можно заюзать при желании, но как по мне лучше в запросе к базе условия писать. Типа order by nameUser desc

Comment: используйте ф-ю [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) – напишите свою ф-ю сортировки, которая бы сравнивала значения поля `nameUser` для возврата -1, 0 или 1.

Comment: Хе, точно забыл, в mysql запросе можно проделать сортировку по полям. Не знаю, вопрос удалять или нет? Всетаки решение интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответа не увидел, полазил в интернете и нашел.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp($a['nameUser'], $b['nameUser']);
});
return $array;
```