# Как сортировать массив по значению?

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть массив:

```
array(3) {
[0] => array(1) {
    [3] => array(5) {
        ["id"] => string(1)
        "7" ["name"] => string(4)
        "Тест3" ["weight"] => int(3)["mincount"] => string(1)
        "8" ["maxcount"] => string(2)
        "40"
    }
}[1] => array(1) {
    [5] => array(5) {
        ["id"] => string(1)
        "9" ["name"] => string(23)
        "Тест5" ["weight"] => int(3)["mincount"] => string(2)
        "12" ["maxcount"] => string(3)
        "300"
    }
}[2] => array(1) {
    [10] => array(5) {
        ["id"] => string(2)
        "14" ["name"] => string(12)
        "Тест10" ["weight"] => int(1)["mincount"] => string(2)
        "20" ["maxcount"] => string(2)
        "40"
    }
}}
```

Нужно его отсортировать по полю weight, чтобы большее стояло в начале. Пробовал с usort, пока не совсем разобрался как работает. Подскажите как решить данную задачку.

Comment: здесь сортировать нечего, сортируют обычно многомерные массивы, приведите пример вашего многомерного массива.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировать массив значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538061/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском или смотрите в похожие своего вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

```
$weights = array_map(function($i) { return current($i)['weight'];}, $arr);
array_multisort($weights, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/904064)

Comment: у него трехмерный

Comment: Точно, array_column не сработает. Обновил ответ